# Theory of Moments: Notation

Tags: probability-theory, polynomials, optimization

I try to read some papers about Moment Matrices/Optimization over polynomials, but I have some troubles with the following notation:

Let $P(V)$ be a power set of some $V=\{1,2,...,n\}$, how does a vector $y \in \mathbb R^{P(V)}$ look like? (same question for $y \in \mathbb R^{{\mathbb Z}^n}$)

Moreover, how to write a matrix given by e.g., $M_t(y):=(y(I \cup J))_{|I|,|J|\leq t}$, where $I,J \subseteq V$, $t\leq n$ and $y(I)$ is a component of the vector $y$ defined above, as matrix? (I am worried about the ordering of the entries of the matrix)

I am also looking for a concrete example of a moment matrix for some given measure, to get some more intuition, but unfortunately I did not find one.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify $P(V)$ with the corners $c(I)\in\{0,1\}^n$ of the hypercube $[0,1]^n$. That assumes that $P(V)$ is "the" power set of $V$, i.e., the family of all subsets.

Now you can identify the corners $c(I)$ of the cube with binary representations

$$b(I)=1+\sum_{i\in I}2^{i-1}$$

of integers $1,...,2^{n}$. This gives an easy ordering for the matrix entries. However, $y(I\cap J)=y_{b(I)\land b(J)}$ using the bitwise "and" is not very arithmetic, so the entries of the vector $y$ will be sprinkled over the matrix.

Another view is to see the vectors $f\in\mathbb R^{P(V)}$ as the coefficient vectors of polynomials

$$f(x)=\sum_{I\in V} f(I)\cdot x_I=\sum_{I\in V} f(I)\cdot \prod_{i\in I}x_i$$

in $n$ variables $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ that have degree of most one in each variable.  The matrix then would represent the action of the operator

$$f\mapsto\sum_{I\subset V} y(I)\cdot x^I\cdot\left[\frac{\partial^{|I|}}{\prod_{i\in I}\partial x_i}f(x)\right]_{x=0}$$

on the subset of these polynomials of total degree less than or equal to $t$.

An application of these interpretations can be found in the paper "Automatic evaluations of cross-derivatives" by Bosse, Griewank, LL, Zimmerman.